# Proper way to authenticate with a web service from Android

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, authentication, credentials

So I have this ASP.NET MVC 4 web app that behaves pretty much like a web service. The client sends a request, the web service returns a JSON object. Now I'm to the point in which I have to authenticate my users from an Android app. What is the proper way to do this on the client side since I no longer have a web browser to store cookies for me to authenticate with the server. SSL is already taken care of.


I have been thinking of several straight forward ways to authenticate but I'm concerned about having some security vulnerability that I might not be aware of.


Is it OK for me to store the user credentials (username and password) in a SQLite database on the Android phone where the app is installed, and then send those credentials along with every request to the server to authenticate? (I'm thinking of hashing the password before storing it in the database, of course).


Is this approach not safe? How do other apps usually authenticate with their services: like eBay, Facebook and such?

Comment: You should also use SSL

Comment: Yes of course. That's already taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data saved in the private storage are relatively secure (on a non rooted device at least). This include :

- sqlite databases (if not made worldreadable)
- [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

If you want a better integration with the account manager (e.g. to have the account listed in the device's settings), you can write an AccountAuthenticator. See [Creating a Custom Account Type](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html) or [Write your own Android Authenticator](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/). Not sure about eBay and Facebook, but that's what Firefox Sync and Evernote  for example do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OAuth 2](http://oauth.net/2/) - many tutorials and implementations are readily available.